# Logging location address to LogCat

Tags: android, eclipse, location, logcat

A part of my app is attempting to update the location (using DDMS with an emulator in Eclipse) and then get the address to print to LogCat.

My code:

```
LocationManager locationManager;
String providerName = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
LocationProvider gpsProvider;

public void enable()
{
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); //Need to ask for this system service

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); //Setting the criteria for the location provider
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(true);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);

    String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    int time = 5000; //Time in ms
    int distance = 5; //Distance in meters

    LocationListener myLocationListener = new LocationListener()
    {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location locations)
        {
            updateLocation(locations);

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, time, distance, myLocationListener);

}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public void findLocation()
{
    gpsProvider = locationManager.getProvider(providerName);

   //String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Location locations = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providerName);

    updateLocation(locations);

}

public void updateLocation(Location locations)
{
    if (locations != null)
    {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

        double latitude = locations.getLatitude();
        double longitude = locations.getLongitude();

        List<Address> addresses = null;
        Geocoder GCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try
        {
            addresses = GCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 10);

            Address first = addresses.get(0);

            Log.d("ADDRESS", first.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }            
    }
}
```

This, to me, should print the value "first" into LogCat but it doesn't seem to actually display anything.

I have the required permission in the manifest so that is not the issue.

Any help that can be provided is great, thank you.

Comment: First of all are confirm that , are you getting latitude and longitude ?

Comment: LogCat isn't printing those either, it's giving a "System.Err" at the line:

    addresses = GCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 10);

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

**See Updated Code**

```
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
 Location locations = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
 List<String>  providerList = locationManager.getAllProviders();
 if(null!=locations && null!=providerList && providerList.size()>0){                 
    double longitude = locations.getLongitude();
    double latitude = locations.getLatitude();
 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());                 
try {
  List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
  if(null!=listAddresses&&listAddresses.size()>0){
     String _Location = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
  }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}

Comment: The new code seems to be fine, however I am still not able to see anything in LogCat

I have placed a log statement in my onLocationChanged function and that's not being displayed either.
My listener is not being picked up I guess?

Comment: PROGRESS
onUpdateLocation and my updateLocation() functions are being entered at least. LogCat is bringing back a "System.err" at the line 
"List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);"

Comment: UPDATE: 
I am able to get the value of the latitude and longitude before entering the try catch. It doesn't seem to be taking the values in, and as mentioned previously, brings a "System.err" at the line "List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);"

Comment: have you tried http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/geocoding.html

Comment: I've just been informed it's because I'm running it on an emulator. Will let you know if it works on my actual phone later on, which it should.